# Determining SARIMAX order for hourly data

Tags: time-series, arima

I'm trying to build SARIMAX model at the moment. My data set consists of hourly data. Plotting the data, there seems to be seasonality in it.

To my knowledge there is a rule for the seasonality order, like 12 for monthly data, 4 for quarterly data. Does anyone know what the order for hourly data? Is it acceptable to set the seasonality order to be 24 since the cycle seems to occur daily?
The
Plot of my data can be found below. The data is shown as blue line. The values can take both negative and positive values

[image]

Comment: Follow this thread to get some hints on hourly data https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+HOURLY+DATA